# Including Boost asio::write.hpp file stops exceptions from being caught?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, boost, boost-asio

After narrowing down everything I see that when I include boost/asio/write.hpp, the exception wont be caught and the application terminates on windows (This app. has requested to terminate...)
However, when I comment just this include line, the exception works perfectly.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::logic_error("aajj");
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Caught:" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

invoked build using these gcc settings

```
g++ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "tests\\so_main.o" "..\\tests\\so_main.cpp" 

g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Xlinker --enable-auto-import -o client.exe "tests\\so_main.o" -lboost_system-mgw45-mt-1_55 -lws2_32
```

Comment: still doesn't compile. did you forget a `using namespace std;` ?

Comment: adding a `using namespace std;` allows this code to compile. it also behaves as expected, catching the logic error and printing "aajj"

Comment: On my system, it is not working. just commenting out this boost hpp inclusion line makes it work. This is a complex project. Could it be that GCC options, libraries or something else is interfering?

Comment: anything from platform to compiler options etc..

Comment: @RichardHodges any idea?. It is really very weird for me as well. I pasted gcc build commands without include and library paths.

Comment: Try to simplify your real example to a working example that still exhibits the behaviour